# What is the equivalent of web.config for JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, configuration, web-config

What is the equivalent of the .NET `web.config` for JavaScript code?

I'm getting to grips with the use of the configuration details in the `web.config` file, but I don't know what (or even if) the configuration options are for JavaScript in the page.

The user case I have is how to have a value the `JavaScript`, in this case a target URL, which can be changed depending upon environment, *DEV / TEST / LIVE*, without changing the `JavaScript` code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could describe a Global JS variable in your master page and use that.

[**Edit**]
In your `web.config` have

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="appEnvironment" value="DEV"/>
</appSettings>
```

In your master page you would have something like this (I would recommend this done in the controller but for easiness)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var envType = "@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings=["appEnvironment"]";
</script>
```

Then all you would need to do is just change the `web.config`. I am presuming you are using MVC

Comment: Thanks for the response, but won't that still necessitate editing the "code" rather than the configuration ?