# Configuration file for HTML + Javascript Project

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, configuration

I am creating a HTML/CSS + Javascript/Jquery project wherein a lot of configuration needs to be maintained. So, I was wondering what would be the best way to maintain a configuration file from which all the settings and stuff could be fetched.

I was planning to have a xml file as a configuration repository, but due to browser specific restrictions and blocks, I am perplexed as to what I should use for having a smooth progress.

Please suggest some. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question, but I got this answer [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795018/what-is-the-equivalent-of-web-config-for-javascript-code) for my question about JavaScript configuration.

Comment: Exactly, I am not too keen on using XML. But does JSON have the same limitations as XML of not working properly on all browsers?

Comment: JSON is pure JavaScript so it works on all browsers. If you need to parse it from a string or serialize an object to a JSON string throw in https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js to shim it for older browsers - but to *use* it in a .js file you don't need anything. It is pure JavaScript after all.

Comment: So, I create a myconfig.js file with all the configurations in json format and parse it using javascript/jquery? Does it work that way?

Comment: Yes, you simply have `var config = {...};` and then use `config.whatever` in your application.

Comment: I created a myconfig.json file, filled it with stuff and read it using getJSON() of jQuery and guess what? Things work like a charm in all browsers! I am testing from my local system though, I hope all will be well when I deploy it in a http server as well. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common way to configure JavaScript applications - both server-side and client-side - is using JSON.

On the server-side, YAML might be worth a thought, too, since many people consider it more readable and even easier to write.

Comment: Is JSON free from the limitations of what XML has for different browsers?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC3 project and was facing the same situation.

I used JSON. I read configuration from DB, created a Dictionary of Key Value pairs at the server side and then sent it to client side on an Ajax call (the JsonResult return type converts your DTO to JavaScript Object that is usable at the client side). There I placed it in a variable at the global level.

Now all my functions (that require configuration values) read that object to determine the course of their execution.