# Generate JSON file from web.config variables

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm building a client-side application as part of a .NET solution. As it's a frontend SPA, this is not an MVC application; it is simply a collection of HTML and Javascript files using node tooling. It'll be pulling RESTful data from a WebAPI project.

I would like to have build profiles through .NET, and I would like to be able to specify configuration through Web.config `appSettings` or `applicationSettings`. As such, I would like to generate a JSON file from these web.config settings.

How can I do that without having to transfer my site to a full MVC site? Are there existing tools for this? (The reason I can't do this is because I'm using a Javascript framework that would not work well with MVC's recommended architecture and directory structure. I'm not looking for CSHTML files or dynamically-generated Javascript).

I'm asking this question here because my searches have only turned up solutions that work with MVC and/or Razor views, or dynamically-generated Javascript through the bundler I'm not using. There's also a way to read the web.config through a Gulp task, but I'm not sure if that's the way that I want to go either.

Thank you.

Edit: I'm using .NET 4.5 on VS2013. I feel this would be much easier with VS2015 as I think they've moved to JSON for some of their project settings.

Edit: This question is somewhat related to what I'd like, but I'm not looking for that specific answer: [What is the equivalent of web.config for JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10795018/677526)

Comment: OK I have no idea what your question is

Comment: Are you asking how to convert the web config, which is XML, to a JSON format, with no other changes?

Comment: @Nikki9696 I'd like to grab specific keys from AppSettings, serialize them to JSON upon application start, and write a file to my project directory. I'm basically trying to avoid having to serve my site as an ASP.NET MVC site, but I want to change my API URLs depending on the Web.config (for development, test, and production endpoints). I'm wondering if there are any tools that already do something like this.

Comment: var test = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings);

Comment: That little snippet got me a few keys in JSOn format. See if that gets what you're after - you can of course grab any keys you like and just use that JSON formatter.

Comment: Oh, and I'm not sure how you're set up, but we have multiple web configs for deploying to different environments. Our build server picks the one that corresponds to where we're deploying. I'd give you more details but I didn't set up the build server  =)

Comment: @Nikki9696 Yup. That's exactly what I want to do here. Doing it in Node is straightforward, and doing it in ASP.NET is straightforward - but trying to marry the ASP.NET configuration with a frontend-only site is what I haven't done yet.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well hopefully the JSON serializer can work for you. Just grab out your keys and write them to a file in Global.asax

Comment: @Nikki9696 Go ahead and add your comments as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In global.asax, you can read the contents of the web config (whichever section you're interested in) as an object, then use JSON serializer to serialize that to a string and output to a file.

Example

```
var test = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(System.Configuration.ConfigurationMa‌​nager.AppSettings);
```

Comment: I think this is the solution. I can build the file and import it using SystemJS. I'll give this a shot tomorrow.

Comment: Additionally - thank you for being so pleasant. I haven't gotten that in the past from the SO .NET community, so it's appreciated.

Comment: I was able to get this to work by converting the appsettings NameValueCollection to a Dictionary for serialization, and then writing the file to the AppDomainAppPath. I don't know if this is the recommended way or the best practice for this type of thing, but I've got what I need. Thank you.